# JSONarray to String without "

Tags: java, json

How can i remove "," from a json array?
thought about a regex but im not familiar with how to filter it or maybe there is an easier way?

my current output is: `["ceratia","direwolf1102","fctwentegirl","nightbot","onecat","sohappybot"]`

and i need it to be:

```
ceratia direwolf1102 fctwentegirl nightbot onecat sohappybot
```

Comment: I don't understand. Just parse the array, and print its values. Or accumulate them with a space as separator.

Comment: Can you share the code you have implemented?

Comment: its hard to share the code since its not all in the same spot :p the thing to know iw that in the end i have a json ARRAY as shown on top and i want to output it without the "," so im looking for a easy way to convert it

Comment: What JSON library are you using? Is it `org.json` or `org.json.simple` or maybe something else? To suggest solution we would need to know API available for this array.

Comment: Anyway general solution would be iterating over array, get each element, printing it or add to StringJoiner with space used as delimiter.

Comment: i made the array into a string with viewerlistMODS = json.getJSONObject("chatters").getJSONArray("moderators").toString(); so i now need to figure out the str.replace function so i can remove the things i dont want to show

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would avoid manipulating string created with `toString()` method, since it is easy to remove things which you don't want to. Lets say your tokens contains `[` or `]`. This means you can't simply call `replace("]","")` because it would remove all `]` including one from string value. Same about `"` or `","`.

Instead simply iterate over array you got, put all tokens in StringJoiner using space as delimiter and then print that joiner.

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(); 
arr.put("foo");
arr.put("bar");

System.out.println(arr);//to show incorrect format

StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(" ");
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++){
    sj.add(arr.getString(i));
}
System.out.println(sj);
```

Output:

```
["foo","bar"]
foo bar
```

Comment: but that would only remove the things based on a given text right? the usernames i posted above will be different every time.

Comment: @user3220962 what do you mean by "based on a given text"? If you are referring to "foo" and "bar" then it is used here just as an example to show difference in results. You can use `JSONArray arr = json.getJSONObject("chatters").getJSONArray("moderators")` to get your own JSONarray with data you want.

Comment: Ahh now i understand x) first i thought about using str.replace step by step and remove the parts one by one but yours is so much easier. :D